# Which TiddlyWiki plugins do you use?

Tags: plugins, productivity, tiddlywiki

I recently started using TiddlyWiki and I think it's a great productivity tool. I was wondering what the most popular and most useful TiddlyWiki plugins are. I already checked out [TiddlyVault](http://tiddlyvault.tiddlyspot.com/) and [TiddlyTools](http://www.tiddlytools.com/) but I think those sites are somewhat unorganized and I'm having a hard time navigating them. What TiddlyWiki plugins do you use and which ones are the must have?

Comment: I use the community wiki plugin

Answer (score 3):

There's also [TiddlyHub](http://plugins.tiddlywiki.org).

Answer (score 1):

Check out my article and links on Tiddlywiki:
http://rajivram.blogspot.com/2009/12/exploring-wikis-tiddlywiki.html

Answer (score 1):

I have been diggin in the same problem (I have TiddlyWiki this week) and from [tiddlytools](http://www.tiddlytools.com/) I have used the following plugins:

- InlineJavascriptPlugin, to enable javascripts.
- EditFieldPlugin, allows keep data input in fields.
- WikifyPlugin, allows variables evalluation using javascript from InlineJavascriptPlugin, it has awfuls examples, but you can figure out his use in a couple of hours.
- RefreshTiddlerPlugin, to refresh tiddler, allowing update with external data or iframes.
- PostFormPlugin, to post dat and sending back to the web, I haven´t personaly test it.
- PersistentFormPlugin, similar to EditFieldPlugin, but with the HTML part of a tiddler.